# Should questions from Oracle Overflow be migrated here?

Tags: discussion, migration, oracle

Should questions from [Oracle Overflow](http://www.oracleoverflow.com/) the StackExchange 1.0 site for Oracle questions be migrated here at some point after the beta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's really up to the Oracle Overflow community.  Each SE1 site has the option of migrating to 2.0, but most of them are choosing to remain separate because if the migrate the have to basically start from scratch with the beta process.

We had a similar scenario with the Audio.SE site.  You can read the discussion here: http://meta.audio.stackexchange.com/questions/67/import-merge-with-socialsounddesign-com

Answer (score 1):

I see @BenV's point and don't disagree. However, what about the option to either

A) "copy the questions over one by one by user" or

B) can SOIS move individual questions from a SE1.0 site to a SE2.0 site at all? If so, then my second option is to move over individual questions on request ... idk if that's really a worthwhile thing tho now that I've taken the time to type out a response.

Posting as an answer so I can get specific feedback on the two points, otherwise it would be merely a comment.

Comment: If we *were* to migrate, it would be all posts, comments, voting, users, credentials in one shot. But that site has only had 7 questions in the last three months. It doesn't seem like that community is very active and we are not likely to import the older data into a brand new site.

Comment: By the same token tho @Robert, it seems like that's exactly the sort of thing that would do well to be folded into a successful site which _does_ get good Oracle turnover. Granted, the number of DBAs needing a specific site is already a small subset, but when we're discussing concentrating for effectiveness, I'm all for it. Ok, I just looked at that site, what's up with Community nowadays? :p Trying to get views on dead questions is it? ;)

Comment: @Robert so is that something that that community could ask for? Already some of those users are over here and seem to be ready for this site to go somewhere. How exactly would that site manage to ask to be migrated? Do the SE1.0 sites have specific metas besides meta.SE? Interesting ...

Comment: @drachenstern: The jury is still out on whether importing 3rd party sites wholesale is helpful or whether it has possibly been harmful to the community activity and general health of the site. Importing is a big deal and we aren't likely to do it unless they benefits are substantial. Besides, we don't own that site so the decision is not ours to make. As a community, you are certainly welcome to make these kinds of connections, whether it is for promotional activities or a source of questions. Has anybody asked *if* they would like to support this site? Make it happen.

Comment: @drachenstern: I didn't see your last comment until I posted my own. So.... To answer your question, only sites that were actually "working" (i.e. more traffic, higher answer rate) were migrated to SE 2.0. SE 1.0 sites only have a meta if *they* created one. Per-site metas were not an automatic, standard part of SE 1.0.

Comment: @Robert ~ The OP on this question is one of the higher ranked users on that site.

Comment: It is specifically because there is no meta for Oracle Overflow and no clear way to contact the owners that I asked this here.

Comment: @Leigh Then I would post a general question on that site asking the users to chime in on if a merge would be preferred.

Comment: @Robert is there any way for someone like Leigh to do that, to contact the original "owners" of the site?

Comment: @Leigh you do know that you can identify the administrators by the double diamonds on this page right? http://www.oracleoverflow.com/users?tab=oldest

Comment: Just to be clear, we will not be merging that site into *this* one. Any support would be more along the lines of contacting users to tell them about DBA-SE or to get the *go ahead* to start asking questions from there over here.

Comment: Ooooooooooooooh

Comment: @drachenstern I assumed as much, but didn't know that specifically.  I'll try posting a question on the site about it.

Comment: @Leigh did you see Robert's last comment above this one? You might want to update http://www.oracleoverflow.com/questions/1005/ to reflect that question...

Comment: @drachenstern Yes, but I'm not sure what it means.  Here is what I have collected from his comments above: 1. A migrate would be everything. 2. We aren't likely to migrate without substantial benefits. 3. 1.0 community decides if migration is done. and then 4. We won't be merging, only talking to users.  The last comment seems to contradict the earlier comments.  Robert can you please clarify?  If the 1.0 community wants a migration will you migrate it?

Comment: @Leigh that's what I gather from his comments too :(

Comment: @Leigh: You should use @Robert (with the '@') if you want him to respond.

Comment: @BenV Normally I do.  Do you know if it needs to be at the start of the comment?  i.e. will your @Robert trigger it?  Also does it need the full name or does it do a search of participants based on the first name?

Comment: @Leigh: All your questions are answered [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020)

Comment: @LeighRiffel and @drachenstern, what Robert is saying is that as that site was not a high traffic/high answer rate/"working" site(#2), it is not a good migration candidate(#4) (though it would be the decision of that community if it were(#3)) as an import includes all data, it isn't a pick-and-choose deal(#1).  However, if that community wants, they can certainly encourage participation here(#4).

Comment: @BenV Thanks, I hadn't seen that.

Comment: Thanks @RebeccaChernoff! That made it much clearer in my eye.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification @RebeccaChernoff given the lack of response from the Oracle Overflow community and the reluctance to migrate it even with community support, I have modified my question on the site to be more of an invitation to dba.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @drachenstern +1 Thanks for your input.  See my above comment.

Comment: @Leigh ~ Indeed. Here's to deciding what we want to do going forward. I have a proposal for a new answer (to keep the flow of conversation for future readers)

Answer (score 0):

I think that given the discussion on this answer: [Should questions from Oracle Overflow be migrated here?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130/should-questions-from-oracle-overflow-be-migrated-here/132#132) that we should allow for individual questions to be duplicated from the old site and that there should be a specific block header at the top that says that it was duplicated from that site, and that links back to the original question, like this:

My reasoning for the sample header is that on the day you copy it (ostensibly the same as the day the question is asked here) people who view the other one will understand that it is "stale" or "active" if they click through. IDK, this is just an idea. But I want to be fair to the OP on the other site. I would love if we could CW the "imports" but I don't think that's an option. This way we can at least attribute proper ownership of the question. If that seems like a lot of headache for importing questions, consider it the price to be paid for borrowing a question from another site.

If you're the OP on both sites then you can omit the second two "lines" of the header, but still identify that it's cross-posted.

What do you think community?

Sample question after the proposed header design

---

```
> **Copied from Oracle Overflow**
>
> http://www.oracleoverflow.com/questions/1005/try-dba-stackexchange-com
>
> [Leigh Riffel](http://www.oracleoverflow.com/users/127/leigh-riffel)
>
> `Viewdate: '2011/01/13' Views: 22 Answers: 0`
```

---

> **Copied from Oracle Overflow**
>
> http://www.oracleoverflow.com/questions/1005/try-dba-stackexchange-com
>
> [Leigh Riffel](http://www.oracleoverflow.com/users/127/leigh-riffel)
>
> `Viewdate: '2011/01/13' Views: 22 Answers: 0`

If you like OracleOverflow, you may also like DBA.StackExhange.com. It is in public beta and while it isn't an Oracle specific site, in only 7 days of private beta it has had 154 questions (33 with the Oracle tag) compared to OracleOverflow's 392. New features are being added to the stack exchange 2.0 platform making it a nicer place for both questions and answers. This is not really a question, but more of a post inviting anyone who wishes to try this new site and perhaps migrate some questions to it.

I've duplicated a few of my questions including the following:

- Why is OS authentication considered poor security for Oracle databases?
- How do you version your Oracle database changes?
- Security for Application Developers doing PL/SQL work in Oracle

Answers to this question could include other questions that have been migrated.

Comment: Interesting idea, but probably overkill particularly for questions re-posted by the OP.  Based on the response I've seen from OO and looking at the questions, I'm not sure there are enough that should be migrated to merit anything special being done.

Comment: @leigh not enough meriting ... oh, well then ... hmmm ... I figured there would be a number that would be worth migrating. idk. At least we have a baseline for discussion at any rate ;)

Comment: Don't just copy and/or post a question just to post it.  Post a question if it is a problem you're having, something that interests you.  Same idea as with the example questions on the proposal.  Don't just blindly ask them.

Comment: @Rebecca ~ Natch, but I would still like to see traceability. I would like to have a community policy of not allowing "blind copies" from OracleOverflow. Is there precedent on SE1.0 questions migrating to SE2.0 sites with overlap like this one has without an active 1.0 community? If there is I bow to that precedent in deference, but I've not heard of such a thing to date on my meta trolling (minimal as it is). Obviously I also don't want to stand contrary to SOIS. I'm just trying to help, ya know? ;)